# How to automatically play music with sound

Tags: html, css, video, mp3

```
<video controls autostart muted>
    <source src="music/1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</video>
```

I tried embed,but it can't auto play.

Comment: you are mixing <audio> and <video> tags, and also most browsers don't enable autoplay with audio as it's annoying

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with **autoplay** attribute, example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp):

```html
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

A note for autoplay attribute by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio):

> Note: Sites that automatically play audio (or videos with an audio track) can be an unpleasant experience for users, so should be avoided when possible. If you must offer autoplay functionality, you should make it opt-in (requiring a user to specifically enable it). However, this can be useful when creating media elements whose source will be set at a later time, under user control. See our autoplay guide for additional information about how to properly use autoplay.